# Usabilla click function does not exist on type

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set up a custom click for a Usabilla survey. I was reading [this article](https://support.usabilla.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003173505-Integrate-Usabilla-with-your-own-feedback-button) and it seems to be working however it's throwing an error when compiling in Angular. I've been searching and I can't seem to find why or find a solution to resolve the error. Any ideas?

This is the error...
"Property 'usabilla_live' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'."

the snippet of code

```
document.getElementById("usabilla_link").addEventListener("click",function(){
  window.usabilla_live("click");
});
```

Comment: You do this npm install --save usabilla-api

Comment: @TomaszVizaint, I've already done that when I was trying anything and everything. Although it's npm install usabilla-api --save